# How to use unicode characters in MariaDB JSON kolumn using Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

One of the attributes of my model is of type JSON. If I use Greek characters ('μ' etc.) in the JSON, they are automatically encoded in MariaDB as unicode characters (e.g. 'μ' is typed as '\03bc'). When I use Eloquent to fetch, the data is automatically converted to valid characters. However, if I want to search for a key in JSON containing the character 'μ' by 'whereJsonContainsKey' it does not find any record. For regular characters, the data is searched normally. How can I search for a row using nonstandard characters?

I'm creating data in this way:

```
$unit = Unit::factory()->create();
        $unit->name = 'Some name';
        $unit->unit = 'Ω';
        $unit->prefixes = ['μ' => 0.000001, 'k' => 1000, 'M' => 1000000];
        $unit->save();
```

then when I wand to fetch:
`$u = Unit::whereJsonContainsKey('prefixes->μ')->first();`
$u = null, but when
`$u = Unit::whereJsonContainsKey('prefixes->k')->first();`
the data is fetched correctly.

Comment: I am neither using laravel nor eloquent but it seems like that you are not the only one having this type of problem. Probably [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/wherejsoncontains-and-special-characters) might help.

Comment: what type is the database field?  what is actually stored in it?  edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` and `select prefixes, hex(prefixes) from yourtablename where name='Some name'` at the mariadb command line

Comment: are you able to show the raw sql your bad whereJsonContainsKey generates?

Comment: Clue from @MarkusSafar helped. I wrote `Json::encodeUsing(fn ($value) => json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))` in boot() in AppServiceProvider and everything works now. Should I write a reply and accept?

Comment: (1) Establish that the client is using UTF-8, (2) Establish that the connection to the database is `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is based on the fact that during json encoding, unicode multibyte characters are encoded using `\uXXXX` by default. This behavior is based on the `json_encode` function provided by php itself.
As statet in the documention for [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), the function accepts  a bunch of flags in form of a bitmask where one of this flags is [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-unicode).

> **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (int)**
> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX).

One viable solution is to force `json_encode` to encode multibyte unicode characters literally by using above flag like `json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`.